# Python & pytz: Figure out if a timezone supports DST and what the DST and non-DST UTC offsets are

Tags: python, pytz

I am using python 2.7.3 and pytz.

For a given timezone which describes a region (e.g. America/New_York), I would like to know if the timezone observes DST during part of the year or not. I care about the present timezone definition in effect. To rephrase the question, given the present timezone definition, will this timezone observer DST (or stop observing it) within the next 365 days?

Additionally, I would like to know what the offset from UTC is for this timezone when it is observing DST and what the offset is when it is not observing DST.

Finally, I would like to know whether or not a given timezone is presently observing DST.

The end goal is to generate a list like this:

```
Name                    Observes DST     DST Offset     non-DST Offset   Presently DST
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
America/New_York        Yes              6              5                No
```

I cannot figure out how to get this information from pytz.

Comment: what about changes to utc offset that are not DST related?

Comment: I was not aware there were such things. Do you mean like when a timezone is redefined from time to time? I am only interested in periodic, twice-a-year UTC offset changes. Are there any periodic, twice-a-year offset changes which are not due to DST?

Comment: I meant changes due to political decisions. They are irregular.

Comment: No, I do not care about irregular changes due to political decisions. For what I need, I only care about changes which will happen in the future and are strictly DST related. So if a timezones used to observe DST but no longer does, I would expect DST=No.

Comment: I have created a solution which sort of works. Create a date in July and one in December. For a given timezone, see if the UTC offsets of the two dates are different. If so, this timezone observes DST. I know what the offsets are, but do not know if the July one is DST or not (think Australia).

Comment: `.dst()` returns non-zero value if DST is in effect. Some timezones may stuck permanently in daylight time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this using this function:

```
def get_tz_dst_info(tz):
    """
    Gets a 3-tuple of info about DST for a timezone. The returned elements are:
    - a boolean if this timezone observes DST
    - a Decimal UTC offset when not in DST
    - a Decimal UTC offset when in DST

    >>> from pytz import timezone
    >>> get_tz_dst_info(timezone('America/New_York'))
    (True, Decimal('-4'), Decimal('-5'))
    >>> get_tz_dst_info(timezone('Europe/Paris'))
    (True, Decimal('2'), Decimal('1'))
    >>> get_tz_dst_info(timezone('UTC'))
    (False, Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'))
    """
    dec_int_offset = timedelta_utc_offset_to_decimal(
        tz.utcoffset(DECEMBER_DATE)
    )
    jul_int_offset = timedelta_utc_offset_to_decimal(tz.utcoffset(JULY_DATE))
    jul_dst = tz.dst(JULY_DATE)
    dec_dst = tz.dst(DECEMBER_DATE)

    dst_offset = dec_int_offset
    non_dst_offset = jul_int_offset
    if jul_dst >= timedelta(seconds=0):
        dst_offset = jul_int_offset
        non_dst_offset = dec_int_offset
    elif dec_dst >= timedelta(seconds=0):
        dst_offset = jul_int_offset
        non_dst_offset = dec_int_offset
    return (dec_int_offset != jul_int_offset,
            non_dst_offset,
            dst_offset)
```

Comment: What is `timedelta_utc_offset_to_decimal`?

Comment: It converts a python `timedelta` into a decimal value. I no longer have the implementation handy.

Answer (score 1):

There is no public interface as far as I know. You could inspect `_utc_transition_times` attribute that is present on `DstTzInfo` (and its subclasses) instances.